# Trigger a HTML-class with external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, hover, font-awesome, onmouseover

I'm using these icons on my webpage: http://fontawesome.io/examples/ 
 
One preset class they use for their icons is `fa-spin`, and it will make the icon spin (du-uh). 
 **I want to make the icons spin whenever they're hovered.**
A snippet of my HTML(The class `"fa fa-envelope"` triggers the icon itself):

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="navbar-item">                
    <span class="icon">
        <i id="wantspin" class="fa fa-envelope fa-spin" onmouseover="dothis()"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Gotta make the `fa-spin`-class trigger somehow by the function `onmouseover`, right?

Here's my javascript code, I know that I haven't done anything yet, other than linking the `id` of the `<i>` with the variable `x`, but I'm kinda lost.

```
function dothis() 
{
var x = document.getElementById ("wantspin")
}
```

I hope it makes sense, and you get the question. I appreciate any help, insight, tips and tricks, thanks.

Comment: I've posted an answer that doesn't use JavaScript, but just for reference: the next step would have been to add the `fa-spin` class: `x.classList.add("fa-spin");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab the `fa-spin` rule from font awesome's stylesheet and add a `:hover` selector:

```css
.spin:hover {
    -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
    animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="http://google.com" class="navbar-item">
    <span class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope spin"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: And here's a vanilla JS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/oa1rzz7y/

Comment: What's your approach for pulling the rule from awesome's stylesheet? `CTRL+F` fa-spin?

Comment: @SyktNorsk Yes :)

Comment: Works perfectly, not really comfortable with javascript yet anyway. Thanks for the other procedures as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Chris G's answer is better.  Here is another answer along the same grain of what you were trying to do.  An even better approach would be to look into jquery and use unobtrusive event handlers instead.

You can ignore my HTML, it's just there so the javascript example works.

```js
function dothis() {
  var el = document.getElementById('wantspin');
  if (el) {
    el.classList.add('fa-spin');
  }
}

function dothat() {
  var el = document.getElementById('wantspin');
  if (el) {
    el.classList.remove('fa-spin');
  }
}
```

```css
#wantspin {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.fa-spin {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="navbar-item">
  <span class="icon">
        <div id="wantspin" class="fa fa-envelope" onmouseover="dothis()" onmouseout="dothat()"></div>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this just add and remove the class in the javaScript and add a onmouseout function to your element. Your html will be this (Notice no fa-spin class).

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="navbar-item">
    <span class="icon">
        <i id="wantspin" class="fa fa-envelope" onmouseover="dothis()" onmouseout="stopthis(this)"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

And your javascript.

```
function dothis() {
    var x = document.getElementById("wantspin");
    x.classList.add("fa-spin");
} 
function stopthis() {
    var x = document.getElementById("wantspin");
    x.classList.remove("fa-spin");
}
```

Comment: No problem I edited my answer as I forgot to put the mouseout event :-S